# PIVPN Wireguard + TOR

Tags: raspbian, vpn

I have installed PIVPN with the Wireguard protocol. So from my mobile phone, for example, my data are encrypted between my mobile phone and VPN but not between my VPN and the Internet. Is there a way to connect my VPN to the TOR network?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve so it's difficult to suggest a proper configuration. Using the TOR network and using a Virtual Private Network are completely different tasks. TOR is to obfuscate your identity on the internet, VPN is to connect to private networks in safe manner. So connecting to your private network by VPN through TOR only obfuscate the already safe encrypted entry point (public ip address) of your VPN. I think it doesn't make much sense and isn't worth the effort. Do you really want this?

Comment: sorry, i would like to hide my ip address on internet. My data are safe encrypted from device to private network but out of my private network? if i have a VPN Wireguard connected and i ask if there is a way to hide my ip for internet because from my device i see my ip public ( ip of my network private )

Comment: In simpler words, here's what happens: Device -> VPN Wireguard on my private network -> go out on internet with my Ip public. I would like to hide ip public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved. First i connect my device ( pc or mobile device ) at my VPN and i connect with tor. In this case, all my  tor request will be stored into packets of VPN tunnel and will be exit on the TOR network

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the entry point to your private network is the public ip address of your internet router with port forwarding. From the private network out to the internet there is a Network Address Translation on the internet router used so all external destination devices (e.g. web server) only see this public ip address as source ip address no matter what client on your private network connected to it. With using the TOR network you can hide this source ip address.

The VPN-client needs the public ip address to connect to your network and to establish the Virtual Private Network so you cannot hide the public ip address on the internet. Connecting to the TOR exit point does not help of course, because preventing reverse finding the source ip address is exactly what TOR is made for.

**Update:**
OK, the answer is only partial correct. I haven't seen that the public ip address isn't masked or hidden by TOR. It is only obfuscated as source ip address in ip packages. It is still available on the internet so it can be used by the VPN-client.